# Redirect apache to tomcat 8 with mod proxy

Tags: apache, webserver, configure, tomcat8

I'm trying to redirect Apache Webserver to Tomcat 8 in Ubuntu. Both of them are working properly but I can't redirect from port 80 in Apache to Tomcat in 8080. My apps work un http://localhost:8080/cms and myapp. I followed [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/proxy-howto.html). I tried also AJP mod but it didn't work.
 I used a2enmod: `a2enmod proxy` and `a2enmod proxy_http` to enable modules.

This is my apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost on

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

ProxyPass         /myapp  http://localhost:8082/myapp
ProxyPassReverse  /myapp  http://localhost:8082/myapp

ProxyPass         /cms  http://localhost:8082/cms
ProxyPassReverse  /cms  http://localhost:8082/cms

</VirtualHost>
```

These are my servlet.xml connectors:

```
   <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8082" proxyPort="80"/>
    <Connector port="8009" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3"/>
```

Using `ProxyPass /cms  http://localhost:8080/`cms don't work either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I added this directly in apache2.conf and it works.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://example:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://example:8080/
    ServerName example.com 
</VirtualHost>
```